# Can the Inbox/Achievements drop-downs be changed to protocol-relative links?

Tags: feature-request, global-inbox

I like to use the Stack Exchange sites via the HTTPS protocol. This is partly because I think this is good practice, and partly because my mobile ISP injects JavaScript into HTTP pages and (perhaps because of the load balancers or proxies they use) page performance tends to be worse on ordinary HTTP sites.

Using HTTPS works fine, with the odd image that still sits on a standard server. However the Inbox and Achievements drop-downs offer links back to Stack Overflow that are hardwired to plain HTTP. Could these panels use protocol-relative links, for a more seamless experience?

Interestingly the main Stack Exchange site explorer drop-down offers everything on a protocol-relative basis, so I imagine it would be possible to do this elsewhere.

Comment: *my mobile ISP injects JavaScript* Wow. Is that... legal? :P

Comment: @Undo Yep, sadly.  Hotels, etc do it too so they can display their own ads.

Comment: I'm actually surprised you're not automatically redirected to https. I can't believe I haven't noticed that before.

Comment: @I3arnon the https support is not yet official. However there are multiple issues related to protocol relative links.

Comment: @rekire What are those issues?

Comment: @Blaise The image links to [i.stack.imgur.com don't use protocol relative links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221304/171881) too.

Comment: [Note that https is currently not officially supported (and we know about the certificate error); but - thanks for calling this to our attention.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232289/212576)

Comment: 2014 + not yet https => never https

Comment: I imagine support for https is [6 to 8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/189578) away...

Comment: Please fix this, annoying as hell.

Comment: @mx: Rob's work-around with NoScript has worked flawlessly since I set it up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To work-around the problem, you could add Stack Overflow to the HSTS list, or use [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/Https-everywhere). With either method, http-URLs are automatically redirected to https.

### Chrome

1. Visit `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`
2. Put "stackoverflow.com" in the "Domain" field.
3. Click Add.
4. ???
5. Profit!

### Firefox

Firefox does not have a built-in HSTS policy editor. You can use add-ons to achieve the desired result though. For instance, with [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/), just add the domain in the box at Advanced -> HTTPS -> Force the following sites to use secure (HTTPS) connections.

[image]

Comment: Ah great, I didn't know about that feature in NoScript! That'll do nicely, thanks Rob.