# Is there a way to force enable HTTPS for my account?

Tags: feature-request, ssl

I noticed recently (middle of 2015) that Stack Overflow is available over HTTP and HTTPS, and HTTPS works perfectly (no mixed content warnings, etc).

Is there a flag I can set for my account to always upgrade the connection to TLS?

In addition you may want to upgrade the description of the `ssl` tag, and/or reopen some old questions about SSL which are now out of date.

Comment: It's been like this [for a while](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216037/175248), but it's not official across the network because of some fun issues with domains (i.e. https://meta.anime.stackexchange.com) will *not* be served via HTTPS).

Comment: This is a [sort-of duplicate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266453/can-the-inbox-achievements-drop-downs-be-changed-to-protocol-relative-links) (the answers will be helpful anyway).

Comment: "HTTPS works perfectly" - sadly no. FF + https everywhere somehow breaks the live updating of pages (e.g. new comment notifications, vote counts).

Comment: I've got a NoScript rule to force `stackoverflow.com` to SSL, and today I just added `graph.facebook.com` to prevent mixed content issues from spoiling the cert validity. I also have `i.stack.imgur.com`, all seems to work pretty well.

Answer (score 39):

Stack Overflow [*does not* fully support HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216037/159034). You'll mostly see mixed content warnings and issues in chat (with logging in), nothing too major that can't be [solved by a script](https://stackapps.com/q/4486/33241).

Stack Exchange *definitely does not* fully support HTTPS. You actually can't visit the meta sites without getting an error about the wildcard certificate.

Just because [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) has enabled the Stack Exchange rules by default, it doesn't mean that it is guaranteed to work everywhere. You should see it listed as *partial*, for the reasons I listed above.

Comment: Ah. Didn't notice this because I never use chat. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score -6):

While we're waiting for SE to do this, you can use [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere). It's pretty great.

Comment: All of the SE sites are only supported in the latest development version, which is downloadable only from their github page (but is perfectly stable).

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this.  [It's not supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216037/175248) and may introduce other bugs which aren't exhibited on a standard user's machine.

Comment: @Makoto the HTTPS Everywhere guys only enable stuff when it's stable. I've been using this on Stack Exchange for ages and everything works just fine.

Comment: Have you paid a visit to the blog?  I installed the latest source and saw content not loading.   I'm reluctant to recommend this plugin's usage even though I want to.

Comment: @Makoto blog.stackoverflow.com isn't loaded over HTTPS for me.

Comment: I use it, but it breaks live updates for me (new comment notifications, live vote counts). So I'd hardly call it "pretty great".